# Is it possible to make Ubuntu One Music respect compilation artist?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, android

It seems like the Ubuntu One Music Android application does not respect the "Compilation Artist" and just makes a whole album, new for each artist in an Album I own (that is made by many people). I have set the "Compilation Artist" to Various Artists but that doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

Not at this point but they are working on it. It's on our horizon to extend the application, but I can't give you any estimated dates at the moment.